# print one time uniqe variable in if or while statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Is there a way to see / print looping variables which have unique values?

for an example:

```
while random.randint(0,15) != 7:
```

If I do:

```
while random.randint(0,15) != 7:
     print (random.randint(0,15))
```

I won't get the same result as it was produced in while loop It can happen while statement generates seven, but print statement would produce different number. So how to see through what variables were you really looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
x = random.randint(0,15)
while x != 7:
     x = random.randint(0,15)
     print (x)
```

Comment: This isn't quite the same because OP's code could never iterate if `randint` returns 7 on the first execution. This version will always iterate at least once.

Comment: then dont init the x to zero... :) I updated @jordanm tnxs for the comments  thoe...:)

Answer (score 2):

You can make function which will print it.

It would be something like this:

```
def rprint(x):
    print(x)
    return x

while rprint(random.randint(0,15)) != 7:
```

Answer (score 0):

Redesign your flow control and store the value of the current random variable:

```
while True:
     rand_ = random.randint(0,15)
     if rand_ != 7:
         continue
     print (rand_)
```